# "Failed to determine a suitable driver class" with Spring Boot / Java project when running compiled jar. But works fine in vscode

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, rest

I'm making a REST API in Java using Spring Boot. And I'm encountering an issue that I don't understand : when I run my code through vscode, everything works just fine. But when I try to run the compiled .jar file, I get the following error message :

```
<message>org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception with message: Failed to determine a suitable driver class</message>
    <frame>
      <class>org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver</class>
      <method>createArgumentArray</method>
      <line>798</line>
    </frame>
```

It is a PostgrSQL database.

I guess that something is probably wrong with my *pom.xml* file ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.languagehub</groupId>
    <artifactId>languagehubpublicapi</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>languagehubpublicapi</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

And here's my *application.properties* file :

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/languagehub
spring.datasource.username = [USER]
spring.datasource.password = [PASSWORD]
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
server.port = 8080
logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate=ERROR
```

Thank you for reading ! If you had any ideas, I'll be really thankful for your help !
I wish you all an excellent day !

**EDIT :** I've modifier the part of *postgresql* dependency in the *pom.xml* file. I now have the following :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

But I'm still getting the same error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is right here:

```xml
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
```

When you say runtime, you're telling maven that the jar will be provided at runtime (as in, deployment) and that it shouldn't include this in the bundling. So when you create your boot jar this dependency isn't getting included. remove `scope` or just added it to the CLI manually (not advised). The default scope is `compiled`

VS code is bridging the gap for you here and putting it on the classpath when you run and you're just not aware.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still getting the same error... I've also tried with the compiled scope. But same result =/

Comment: when you do `mvn clean install`, check the `target` directory and see if there is a postgres jar i there. I don't know how you're doing your bundling, but make sure you do it from the CLI and not in VS. That way for SURE your know what's going on. I am 100% confident that's what the problem is. If it's still not working, then dig deeper into why it's not being bundled.

Comment: Thanks a lot !! Compiling through the Java Project or Maven section of vscode wasn't working. But with the CLI everything work just fine. Thanks again =)

Comment: How about an upvote too? :)

Comment: It seems that I don't have enough reputation... :(

Comment: Oh well. Keep at it

Answer (score 0):

have You tried removing `<scope>runtime</scope>` from postgresql dependency?

Comment: I've removed it. But I'm still getting the same error =/

Comment: you can leave this comment on the post it self